# Is there anyway to decrease code from identical if statement?

Tags: javascript

```
var cl=[],di=[],sp=[],he=[];
for(var i=0;i<arg.length;i++){
    if(arg[i].slice(0,2)==='cl'){cl.push(arg[i])};
    if(arg[i].slice(0,2)==='di'){di.push(arg[i])};
    if(arg[i].slice(0,2)==='sp'){sp.push(arg[i])};
    if(arg[i].slice(0,2)==='he'){he.push(arg[i])};
}
```

Here i have 4 if statement;which are identical how can i reduce code.

Comment: `switch(..) { case: ... default:}` ... profit

Comment: For Code Reviews visit http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah ...switch() reduce little bit but i am not searching for switch. Thanks .

Comment: @SakulBudhathoki Can you add complete code with example

Comment: In order to advise on your code, we're going to need to see more context of the wider program.

Answer (score 2):

There's more than on way to do this. Here the 2 ways i know :

Use a `switch` statement :

```
switch((arg[i].slice(0,2)) {
    case 'cl' : cl.push(arg[i]); break;
    case 'di' : di.push(arg[i]); break;
    case 'sp' : sp.push(arg[i]); break;
    case 'he' : he.push(arg[i]); break;
}
```

Put your arrays in an object and use the `[]` notation :

```
var cl=[],di=[],sp=[],he=[];
var map = {
    cl : cl,
    di : di,
    sp : sp,
    he : he
};

for(var i=0;i<arg.length;i++){
    var key = arg[i].slice(0,2);
    if (map[key]) map[key].push(arg[i])
}
```

Comment: Given the example code, the second solution is much superior.

Answer (score 0):

Not really because you have separate variables for each array. (Though you can use `switch` or `if else` to improve performance.)

However, if you make the arrays part of a single object, you can reduce the if statement code quite a bit. Like this for example:

```
var myArrays = {
    cl: [],
    di: [],
    sp: [],
    he: []
};

function pusher(arg) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        // Check to ensure length is at least 2 characters.
        if(arg[i].length < 2)
            continue;

        var a = arg[i].slice(0, 2);

        // Check to ensure value exists in myArrays.
        if(myArrays[a])
            myArrays[a].push(arg[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course I have added extra validation so if end up with plenty of lines still. But it's much more re-usable and caters for your scenario.

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/799pdg54/2/)

---

If you only have 4 arrays then that's fine, but perhaps this is a cut down example? You may want to consider dynamically creating the arrays if that is the case. As a quick example:

```
var myArrays = {};
myArrays['cl'] = [];
myArrays['di'] = [];
// etc...
```

You can create as many as you need to with this method, and can even base it off of some list if you need to.